# Python printing random numbers in functions

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to make a dice rolling simulator, I haven't come very far, and I already have a problem.

Here's my code:

```
#Dice roll simulation

from random import *

#The minimum and maximum numbers on the dice
min = 1
max = 6

#The function for rolling the dice. Should print a number between 1 and 6...
def roll (min, max):
number = random.randint(min, max)
    print(number)
    return

roll(min, max)
```

The function 'roll' should print out a random number between 1 and 6, but instead, I get this error message whenever I run the program:

> C:\Users\Sebastian\PycharmProjects\minigames\venv\Scripts\python.exe 
>   C:/Users/Sebastian/PycharmProjects/minigames/diceroll.py Traceback
>   (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:/Users/Sebastian/PycharmProjects/minigames/diceroll.py", line 15, 
>   in 
>       roll(min, max)   File "C:/Users/Sebastian/PycharmProjects/minigames/diceroll.py", line 11, 
>   in roll
>       number = random.randint(min, max) AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute  'randint'
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: Remove random from the call and just have randint, also indent the first line in function if it is not but assume a typo

Comment: Try import random or leave the random off your function call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Why is your code failing?**

The problem is with your `import` statement.

**How to correct it?**

Your code contains, `from random import *` as the first statement. This imports all the items present in random.py. Thus the below code will work.

```
from random import *
print(randint(1,6))
```

The other option is to import the module as below.

```
import random
print(random.randint(1,6))
```

Among the above two approaches, the good practice is to use the second type. Reason is when your code grows, it will be easy to identify the source of the called function.

Answer (score 3):

`random` modules includes the `randint` method, so either:

1. replace`from random import *` with `import random`
2. replace `random.randint` with `randint` as Ab Bennt suggested.